# C# continue/goto Basic query

Tags: c#

I have this kind of code:

```
main()
{
   for(i=0;i<100;i++)
   {
   if(cond1)
       func(1); //Just some logics are present here
   if (cond2)
      if(cond3 | cond4)
          func(2);
and so on....
   }
}

void func(int)
{
   do somthing;
   if cond5
      continue;// this is for the FOR loop in main() & I know this doesnt make sense.
}
```

So, Depending on some IF condition in the function 'func', I want to 'continue' the FOR loop present in main(). How to achieve this?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return bool from your function and continue on false.  Using your example:

```
main()
{
   for(i=0;i<100;i++)
   {
   if(cond1)
       func(1); //Just some logics are present here
   if (cond2)
      if(cond3 | cond4)
          if (!func(2))
             continue;
and so on....
   }
}

bool func(int)
{
   do somthing;
   if cond5
      return false;
   return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Change your func function return type to bool so it will return true if condition is satisfied and false otherwise.
2. In your for loop check func return value. If it is try - call continue. Otherwise - do nothing.

   ```
   void main()
       {
          for(i=0;i<100;i++)
          {
           if(cond1)
              if (func(1))
                  continue;//Just some logics are present here
          if (cond2)
             if(cond3 | cond4)
                 if (func(2))
                     continue;
           and so on....
          }
       }
   bool func(int)
   {
       do somthing;
       bool bRes = false;
       if cond5
           bRes = true;// this is for the FOR loop in main() & I know this doesnt make sense.
       // ....
       return bRes;
   }
   ```

Comment: Good answer but you might have added some text about how you changed (improved) the programflow.